# select a specific set of cell under a set of tables using python and beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

1. Consider there are N web pages.
2. Each web page has one or more tables. The common thing the tables have is that their class is same, consider "table_class."
3. We need the contents under the same column[third column, heading is title] of every table.
4. Contents meaning, the href links in column three from all rows.
5. Some rows might just be plain text and some might have href link in them.
6. You should print each href link in a separate line, one after the other.
7. Using attributes to filter is not valid as some tags have different attributes. The position of the cell is the only hint available.

How do you code this?

Consider these two links for the web pages:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Telugu_films_of_2014
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Telugu_films_of_2013

Consider the table: wikitable

Required content: href links of column Title

Code I tried for one page:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer


content = urlopen("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Telugu_films_of_2015").read()  
filter_tag = SoupStrainer("table", {"class":"wikitable"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, parse_only=filter_tag)

for sp in soup.find_all('tr'):
    for bt in sp.find_all('td'):
        for link in bt.find_all('a'):
            print(link.get("href"))
    print()
```

Comment: Much easier to follow would be to have an example input HTML and the desired output.

Comment: I don't need to learn your homework, what don't you tell us what you have done already.

Comment: @PepperoniPizza Added. I have 7 other codes too, but none of those got me what I need so did not add any code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to iterate over every `table` with `wikitable` class; for every `table` find links directly inside the `i` tag directly inside `td` directly inside `tr`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Telugu_films_of_2014"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content)

# iterate over tables
for table in soup.select('table.wikitable.sortable'):
    # get the table header/description, continue if not found
    h3 = table.find_previous_sibling('h3')
    if h3 is None:
        continue
    print h3.text

    # get the links
    for link in table.select('tr > td > i > a'):
        print link.text, "|", link.get('href', '')

    print "------"
```

Prints (also printing table names for clarity):

```
January 2014–june 2014[edit]
Celebrity | /wiki/Celebrity
Kshatriya | /wiki/Kshatriya
1: Nenokkadine | /wiki/1:_Nenokkadine
...
Oohalu Gusagusalade | /wiki/Oohalu_Gusagusalade
Autonagar Surya | /wiki/Autonagar_Surya
------
July 2014 – December 2014[edit]
...
O Manishi Katha | /wiki/O_Manishi_Katha
Mukunda | /wiki/Mukunda
Chinnadana Nee Kosam | /wiki/Chinnadana_Nee_Kosam
------
```

Comment: can I ask how is it selecting the 1st 'i' or 1st 'a' and printing them only, because with my other codes, it was printing all the other contents in "a" from other td's.

Comment: @bsy the key trick here is using that `i` element - if you see, only the title column has the contents in the italic font.

Comment: Oh wow, awesome. So I've learned to observe the very minute things today. I thank you for the good explanation.